# Can't recieve notifications when Mobile phone is turned on from shutdown state

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on an app that receives notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging in flutter.

I can receive notifications in **Background**, **Terminated**, and **Foreground** perfectly.

However, when I try to turn off(Shut it down) my phone and send notifications from FCM Console I only receive the latest sent notification or sometimes I don't receive anything at all.

For example, I sent **4 notifications** from the FCM console when my Phone is shut down(dead) when I turn it on again. Instead of receiving **1, 2, 3, 4** notifications I only receive the last notification **4** and sometimes none at all!

Any links to read and any details as to why this behaviour is occuring is a very big help.